# Magento 2 :- How to add join query in single trail

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

working fine, I want to join  query in my custom module

```
/**
     * Lazy loads the requested post
     * @return Post
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function getPost()
    {
        if ($this->_post === null) {
            /** @var Post $post */
            $post = $this->_postFactory->create();
            $post->load($this->_getPostId());
            if (!$post->getId()) {
                throw new LocalizedException(__('Trails not found'));
            }
            $this->_post = $post;
        }
        return $this->_post;
    }
```

**
 Query

```
  $postCollection->getSelect()->join( array('customer_entity'=> $postCollection->getTable('customer_entity')), 'customer_entity.entity_id = main_table.entity_id');
```

Comment: Please confirm your Magento version? It can't be Magento 1.x and 2.x at the same time.

Comment: Magento CLI version 2.2.3